# How to change pager text in jquery cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the text of the jquery cycle pager element. By default is is 1, 2, 3 etc. I would like to just make a customized name for each one. Here is the url:

http://www.rockymountainsports.ca/web/layout.html

Any help is great,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var titles = ['Pentiction Summer Classic', 'Ryan Kesler', 'Trevor Linden'];
    $('.slideshow').after('<div id="navigation"><div id="nav"></div></div>').cycle({
        fx:     'fade', 
        timeout: 5000, 
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            return '<a href="#">' + titles[index] + '</a>';
        }
    });
});
```